# how to change look of the scroller of NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I want to change the appearance of the vertical scroller of my NSTableView. Specifically, I want to change the width of it as well as the knob.

I'm trying to do it by subclassing NSScroller and overwriting drawRect and drawKnob...but so far no results there...

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Comment: How are you making the table use your subclass?  Is the table created by a nib, where you can set the class of the scroller?

Comment: In my experience, `drawRect:` never gets called in an NSScroller subclass, but `drawKnob` and `drawKnobSlotInRect:` do get called.

Comment: I found a workaround...see my answer

Comment: JWWalker is correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So...after some substantial research I found a solution (workaround)

In order to change the look of my scroller I subclassed NSScroller and overwrote some methods there:

```
#import "HSObjectLibraryScroller.h"

@implementation HSObjectLibraryScroller

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect;
{
   if (self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect])
   {}
   return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
   CGContextRef context = (CGContextRef) [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
   CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 64.0f/255.0f,64.0f/255.0f,64.0f/255.0f,1.0);
   CGContextFillRect(context, NSRectToCGRect(dirtyRect));

   [self drawKnobSlot];
   [self drawKnob];
}

- (void)drawKnobSlot;
{
    NSRect slotRect = [self rectForPart:NSScrollerKnobSlot];
    NSRect r = NSMakeRect(slotRect.origin.x, slotRect.origin.y, 4, slotRect.size.height);
    NSImage* slotTop = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"top_slider"
                                                                                            ofType:@"png"]];

    NSImage* slotVertFill = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"centerVert_slider"
                                                                                                      ofType:@"png"]];

    NSImage* slotBottom = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Bottom_slider"
                                                                                             ofType:@"png"]];

    NSDrawThreePartImage(r, slotTop, slotVertFill, slotBottom, YES, NSCompositeSourceOver, 1, NO);

}
- (void)drawKnob;
{
    NSRect knobRect = [self rectForPart:NSScrollerKnob];
    NSRect r = NSMakeRect(knobRect.origin.x, knobRect.origin.y, 4, knobRect.size.height);
    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:255.0f/255.0f green:197.0f/255.0f blue:84.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] set];
    NSRectFill(r);
}
@end
```

This implementation gave me following result:

[image]